# How to override CSS transitions for particular elements?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to know if there is a quick/smart way to override CSS transitions for particular elements within the HTML document?

If we have this CSS definition setup, which will apply a transition to all elements:

```
* {
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

How would I override that CSS transition effect for text elements, so that all text will not have the transition applied to it? Note, this covers all elements such as p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, etc, as well as element that contain text, such as I'm some freaky text.

The below code snippet is an example of what should NOT happen. The background-color change transition is what is expected to happen, but the text should not transition.

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.egodiv {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.egodiv:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="egodiv">Look at me now!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Frankly, `transition:all` on everything is messy. You will spend more time turning it off when it's not required than you will defining it on the elements you do want. Plus, I think you might have some performace and layout issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to turn off transitioning for a specific style, is to redefine the transition property altogether. This is fine as long as you know the original transition value:

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.egodiv {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out, font-size .01s linear;
}

.egodiv:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="egodiv">Look at me now!</div>
```

I assumed it was the `font-size` you wanted to disable transitioning on.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.egodiv {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  transition:none; // override transition
}

.egodiv:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="egodiv">Look at me now!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as he want to overwrite it is better to use `transition:none !important;`

Comment: @Alaeddine No, it's not. Using `!important` where completely unnecessary is exactly what you *shouldn't* be suggesting.